# Getting issue while converting the string value 2019-03-15-15.22.25.163529 into Datetime in Bigquery

Tags: sql, date, google-bigquery

I am trying to parse the string value `2019-03-15-15.22.25.163529` coming from a file into `DATETIME` in Bigquery but getting an error.

Query:

```
select PARSE_DATETIME('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%s', '2019-03-15-15.22.25.754892')
```

Error:

> Failed to parse input string "2019-03-15-15.22.25.754892"

Comment: And what have you tried to debug this problem?

Answer (score 2):

There are several problems with your format specifier:

- seconds are `%S`, not `%s` (which stand for the epoch timestamp)
- better yet, you can use `%E*S` for seconds and their fractional part
- the space between the date and time parts should be a dash instead (`-`)
- the separator between hours, minutes and seconds is `.` instead of `:`

Consider:

```
PARSE_DATETIME('%Y-%m-%d-%H.%M.%E*S', '2019-03-15-15.22.25.754892')
```